# Power BI desktop with custom charts

Tags: powerbi

I have created a report using Power BI desktop and I upload online. I used two charts that I download them from this site:https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/. The problem is that in the online dashboard the charts are not showing properly today. They are simple not loaded at all. Any idea/solution?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the custom visuals to the app.powerbi.com as well.